# Quais são as dependências que necessito no Gradle?

Tags: java, web-service, gradle

Quais são as dependências necessárias para as seguintes bibliotecas?

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnection;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `javax.xml.parsers`

O pacote `javax.xml.parsers` corresponde ao JAXP e pode ser encontrado no [`jaxp-api-1.4.5.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.parsers/jaxp-api/1.4.5). Para o Gradle, você usaria isso:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.parsers', name: 'jaxp-api', version: '1.4.5'
```

Ele também é distribuído na biblioteca padrão. No Java 9 ele está no [módulo `java.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml-summary.html).

## `javax.xml.soap`

O pacote `javax.xml.soap` corresponde ao SAAJ e pode ser encontradas no [`saaj-api-1.3.5.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/saaj-api/1.3.5). Para o Gradle, você usaria isso:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.soap', name: 'saaj-api', version: '1.3.5'
```

Ele também é distribuído na biblioteca padrão. No Java 9 ele está no [módulo `java.xml.ws`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.ws-summary.html), mas como esse módulo está marcado com `@Deprecated(since="9", forRemoval=true)`, então é melhor importá-lo como biblioteca no Gradle do que usar o módulo padrão do Java 9. Isso não significa que o SAAJ foi descontinuado ou abandonado, significa apenas que ele não será mais distribuído como parte da JDK após o Java 9, devendo então ser adicionado como uma dependência externa (exatamente o que o Gradle faz).

## `java.net`, `java.io` e `java.util`

Os pacotes `java.net`, `java.io` e `java.util` estão na biblioteca padrão. No Java 9, todos eles estão no [módulo `java.base`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.base-summary.html). Assim sendo, você não precisa fazer nada de especial no Gradle para usá-los.

## `org.w3c.dom` e `org.xml.sax`

Os pacotes `org.w3c.dom` e `org.xml.sax` também estão na biblioteca padrão. No Java 9, eles estão no [módulo `java.xml`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml-summary.html).

Comment: As bibliotecas baixaram corretamente, e agora?

:runErro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal LoadWebService FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin\java.exe'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @EduardoWeise Isso daí aparenta ser um outro erro diferente, acho (não tenho certeza) que quer dizer que ele não achou a classe `LoadWebService` que seria a classe principal (aquela com o `public static void main(String[] args)`). Recomendo que poste uma outra pergunta e coloque nela o código completo do seu arquivo de configuração do Gradle.